# Add administration nav menu in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a new module for PrestaShop 1.7 and I want to add a new menu to the main admin's navbar and link it to an admin section of my module. But the documentation is a drop in the ocean and I can't get how to do this.
Any ideas ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a link to the left menu to a admin controller in your module, you can use something like:

```
// for example if you want to create inside the Orders menu or use 0 to create a top menu.
$parentTabID = Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminParentOrders'); 
$tab = new Tab();
$tab->active = 1;
$tab->class_name = "AdminCustom"; // you custom class
$tab->name = array();
foreach (Language::getLanguages() as $lang){
    $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = "Link name";
}
$tab->id_parent = $parentTabID;
$tab->module = $this->name;
$tab->add();
```